# Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::create() laravel-5.8

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

hi m trying to download db data in excel format,,, but when I click on download then it says: Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::create()

code of controller:

```
    function excel()
{
 $pdf_data = DB::table('importpdfs')->get()->toArray();
 $pdf_array[] = array('Battery', 'No_of_questions_attempted', 'SAS', 'NPR', 'ST', 'GR');
 foreach($pdf_data as $pdf)
 {
  $pdf_array[] = array(
   'Battery'  => $pdf->Battery,
   'No_of_questions_attempted'   => $pdf->No_of_questions_attempted,
   'SAS'    => $pdf->SAS,
   'NPR'  => $pdf->NPR,
   'ST'   => $pdf->ST,
   'GR'   => $pdf->GR
  );
 }
 Excel::create('Pdf Data', function($excel) use ($pdf_array){
  $excel->setTitle('Pdf Data');
  $excel->sheet('Pdf Data', function($sheet) use ($pdf_array){
   $sheet->fromArray($pdf_array, null, 'A1', false, false);
  });
 })->download('xlsx');
}
```

Comment: which version of `laravel-excel` are you using?

Comment: m following this tutorial   https://www.webslesson.info/2018/05/how-to-export-mysql-data-to-excel-file-in-laravel.html

Answer (score 1):

The create method was removed with `laravel-excel` version `3.0`.

From the [upgrade guide](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/upgrade.html#upgrading-to-3-from-2-1):

> Excel::create() is removed and replaced by
>   Excel::download/Excel::store($yourExport)

I would use the [quickstart guide](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/) from their documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you previously updated your `"maatwebsite/excel"` package to 3.*. version, the method `Excel::create($yourExport)` is removed. Instead you should use `Excel::download/Excel::store($yourExport)`.

Example how it should be used with new version:

```
use App\Exports\UsersExport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UsersController extends Controller 
{
    public function export() 
    {
        return Excel::download(new UsersExport, 'users.xlsx');
    }
}
```

Where `UsersExport` is a new class created by using the `make:export` command.

**UsersExport.php:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\User;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

class UsersExport implements FromCollection
{
    public function collection()
    {
        return User::all();
    }
}
```

Here you can find official [Upgrade guide](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/upgrade.html) to a new version.

Comment: ur code says:  Cannot use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel as Excel because the name is already in use,,,,,,,,,,,my complete controller:    paste.ofcode.org/SeVEButgRyNWD3gsB9kyEt

Comment: You are importing Excel two times. Remove `use Excel` from your code. Also, use the guide that I provided and follow it step by step, your controller code is wrong.

Comment: Undefined class constant 'download'         at   Excel::download/Excel::store('Pdf Data', function($excel) use ($pdf_array){

Comment: I told you, your code is wrong. You should use only one `Excel::download` or `Excel::store`. As an argument, you don't pass that query anymore, but a new class that you created using `make:export` command in your console. Again, please follow the upgrade documentation step by step.

Comment: @zlantangoralija it says:  Argument 2 passed to Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::download() must be of the type string, object given, called in D:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\webpro3\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 237  ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,where as my current code is paste.ofcode.org/54g7BaejEDu8r5ZBfJMvih,,,,,,can u plz update ur answer once?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not using the Facade and using the file directly, make sure you are using

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
```

and not

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel;
```

Comment: I add it in the controller but it says: Cannot use Excel as Excel because the name is already in use

Comment: Are there any other `use ...\Excel;` statements in that controller? If so, remove them (if not used anywhere in your code) and see if it works, otherwise you can try `use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel as Foo;` and call `Foo::create();` instead of `Excel::create();`.

Comment: my complete code:    paste.ofcode.org/SeVEButgRyNWD3gsB9kyEt

Comment: Remove the `use Excel;` on line 8.

Comment: Undefined class constant 'download'

Comment: Like @Alex said, remove use Excel;

Comment: Excel::download('Pdf Data', function($excel) use ($pdf_array){
      $excel->setTitle('Pdf Data');
      $excel->sheet('Pdf Data', function($sheet) use ($pdf_array){
       $sheet->fromArray($pdf_array, null, 'A1', false, false);
      });
     })->download('xlsx');

Comment: Or for now just simply do Excel::download($pdf_array, 'pdfdata.xlsx');

Comment: @shahburhan by using this:   Excel::download($pdf_array, 'pdfdata.xlsx');     it shows only blank screen

Comment: Does the file download?